# Method sets a variable to an instance during execution but then sets it back to null at the end of execution

Tags: c#

The method named `MoveToANewRoom(Room newRoom)` is supposed to set a variable to an instance, and it does this during the course of the method, but at the end the variable is set back to null for no discernible reason.

I ran the code in the debugger and saw that the variable named `currentRoom` was set to `room1` as intended during the execution of the method `MoveToANewRoom(Room newRoom)`. However, when the method is finished executing, the variable `currentRoom` is set back to `null` again.

Am I missing something really basic?

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Room currentRoom;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Room room1 = new Room("Living Room");
            Room room2 = new Room("Dining Room");
            Room room3 = new Room("Kitchen");
            Room room4 = new Room("Front Yard");
            Room room5 = new Room("Back Yard");
            Room room6 = new Room("Garden");
            room1.Exits = new Room[] { room2, room3 };
            room2.Exits = new Room[] { room1, room4 };
            room3.Exits = new Room[] { room1, room4 };
            room4.Exits = new Room[] { room2, room3, room5, room6 };
            room5.Exits = new Room[] { room4 };
            room6.Exits = new Room[] { room4 };
            MoveToANewRoom(room1); 
        }
        public class Room
        {
            public string Name;
            public Room[] Exits;
            public Room(string name)
            {
                this.Name = name;
            }
        }
        public void MoveToANewRoom(Room newRoom)
        {
            Room currentRoom = newRoom;
            exits.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < currentRoom.Exits.Length; i++)
            {
                exits.Items.Add(currentRoom.Exits[i].Name);
                exits.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've redeclared `currentRoom` at function scope. This hides the one at class scope.

Comment: So the debugger displayed the value of the function scope variable during the execution of the method and then displayed the class scope variable after the method finished executing? Was I misled by the debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are defining a local variable `currentRoom` that is specific to the method.

```
currentRoom = newRoom;
```

Is the correct syntax to accomplish a permanent change.

EDIT:

For clarification as to why your debugger showed you the wrong information:

It was showing you the contextual value that you selected. In this case `currentRoom` meant something different inside `MoveToANewRoom` so it "helpfully" update the value for you. As to whether there should be more clarification in cases like this has been subject to many debates :).

Comment: Wow it worked! I didn't know that using the class name in front of the variable name would define a local variable. Thank you.

Comment: So, wait, did the local variable hide the global variable whilst the method was running, and then got deleted so the global variable reappeared after the method finished running?

Comment: @user2108462 If you are interested, here is the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691134(v=vs.71).aspx) on name hiding through nesting, and the sidebar has links to other information about scopes.